# Link picture to facebook status (using graph API)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried almost everything to link picture to Facebook status that is created via Facebook Graph API from other web application.

I am sending POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed with these fields:

```
message = text that is correctly displayed
link = link to page that also works well
picture = link to picture that I want to display in status (not working)
type = picture
```

I have tried to use source field instead of picture field, tried to ommit type field, I have also tried to use picture directly as a link field.

I have also tried to use picture (or source) field to point on URL directly with picture data, or to page containing that image mentioned in og:image meta tag.

None of mentioned worked. I can only post a status with text and correct link, picture is never included. On the other hand, I have realized, that link to my picture is wrapped in some Facebook link (this is visible in element inspector in one of div elements of status on Facebook wall), but this link does not work – it shows gray gif picture large 1px by 1px. I have tried to remove all special characters from link, now it is in simple form eg. foo.bar/some/path/picture12.

Nothing worked

Comment: _“now [the link] is in simple form eg. foo.bar/some/path/picture12.”_ – but you did include http://, right? I don’t see any value in providing type=picture here, since you want to post a link. Does that link go to your own site? If so, have you tried to supply the desired picture in there directly in OG meta tags? And did you put that URL through the Facebook debugger already?

Comment: yes, http:// is included, i am sure that link is correct. i have read that facebook has problem with '-' (dashes), so I have removed them as well. That link goes to our site. This site contains og:image meta tag. I also used Facebook lint (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) (and it says that og:image tag should be OK) - but now I see taht thumbnail in that Debug section shows blank image, but it links to correct image that is displayed properly in all browsers (all headers like mime type are set correctly)

Comment: Can you give the URL of that page your are trying to post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you include the link to in the post:
`link=http://url.to.your.canvas.app/another.link`

The link provided as a landing page needs to be on the same domain as the one you have specified in the application settings on developers.facebook.com

Also instead of `me` you should use your `Facebook ID` ( as a good practice )`

Comment: page and picture are both on the same domain. I have tried to use static picture (eg. http://something.com/picture.jpg) and this link worked well. I need to use url for picture in a form http://something.com/gallery/images?photoUUID=46454645646454545. I tried to use facebook ID sa well, but behaviour is the same. I hope that there is no problem because of missing .jpg or file type extension from link

Comment: Interesting... The link of the picture does not need to be on the same domai as the application, and also the .jpg extension is optional. If the static worked, try then to see if the dynamic url it's not blocking the Facebook scrapper

Comment: check this location for the ip of the scraper https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper

Comment: Thank you @valentinvieriu, after adding those IP ranges to firewall white list all work well.